# How do you overwrite a OneToMany mapping with JPA?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, tomcat

I have a One to many mapping in JPA as follows:

In my blockchain class I have the @OneToMany annotation over ArrayList (which is the "chain" property) for which I have a Block class.

I have a method for replacing the chain of a blockchain instance with another when a new chain is broadcast or new block is broadcast on the wire (e.g. pubsub, triggred by async listener). The method replaces the chain if it is found to be valid and of sufficient length.

The chain is reflected in the database as a join table between blockchain and block. When a new chain comes in, it will be mostly identical. In other words there will be at least 1 collision with primary key, if only its the genesis block. More likely all but one or a few blocks at the tip will collide, so I want the ability to handle this without incident. Ideally JPA would have figured out how to do it without me with the following code, but that's not the case.

```java
    @Override
    public boolean replaceChain(String name, ArrayList<Block> new_chain) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, ChainTooShortException, GenesisBlockInvalidException, BlocksInChainInvalidException {
        this.connect();
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        Query query = em.createQuery("select b from Blockchain b where b.instance_name = :name");
        query.setParameter("name", name);
        Blockchain blockchain = (Blockchain) query.getSingleResult();
        blockchain.replace_chain(new_chain);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        this.disconnect();
        return true;
    }
```

From there I tried many permutations and tricks I could think of. I tried manually deleting each block that is a duplicate from the block entity but then it had a problem with the join table and stack overflow said apparently JPA is not set up to manage that manually. It's not the OOP way. I'm fine with that, but then my question is what is the OOP way. Just to overwrite a one to many relationship. The new incoming OneToMany should overwrite everything, displace everything else and that's it, but it tries to duplicate. I read other SO posts but I either didn't understand them well enough or they didn't see to help.

I'm running this through a DAO service, wired up to work through a pubnub listener callback. I have two servers and in fact codebases running- this Main "node on the network" that is dealing with the database (port 8080) and an "in memory" one on 9080 that starts with only the genesis block and if it gets a 200 GET request to 8080 will clone that and replace that chain. Replace chain works- just not to write to database. I call the second node on the network the PEER instance. It has the ability to mine blocks and when it does, it broadcasts to pubsub which triggers the main node. That's my setup. Everything seems to be working beautifully except the JPA part of it. I'm using Eclipselink and Tomcat.

From my understanding, when you start a transaction with entitymanager, it basically watches what you do and takes notes and records the results and does its magic, kind of like a scribe or observer. You set it up to watch, and then you do your business and then you tell it to commit, it still has limits and constraints to deal with or exceptions will be thrown but that's my understanding and that's the route I initially went.

Here is my error log for just this code above, not the trying to manually delete the blocks of a given chain. I could do that but I couldn't get to the join table and I know that's not the ideal way

```
Error Code: 1062
Call: INSERT INTO block (TIMESTAMP, DATA, DIFFICULTY, HASH, LASTHASH, NONCE) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    bind => [1617166967254, [B@5ebbe21e, 9, 002057d17e0de9c5f97f6a0f3e7534c0599036ae307ece2ee3f645025c153f80, 007e833b320c58bcf29096e22ced52a5c90c915e23830eeae0a7093290af4080, 246]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(privblock.gerald.ryan.entity.Block@d6f817c0)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionImpl.commit(EntityTransactionImpl.java:157)
    at privblock.gerald.ryan.dao.BlockchainDao.replaceChain(BlockchainDao.java:97)
    at privblock.gerald.ryan.service.BlockchainService.replaceChainService(BlockchainService.java:38)
    at pubsub.PubNubSubCallback.message(PubNubSubCallback.java:132)
    at com.pubnub.api.managers.ListenerManager.announce(ListenerManager.java:61)
    at com.pubnub.api.workers.SubscribeMessageWorker.processIncomingPayload(SubscribeMessageWorker.java:228)
    at com.pubnub.api.workers.SubscribeMessageWorker.takeMessage(SubscribeMessageWorker.java:83)
    at com.pubnub.api.workers.SubscribeMessageWorker.run(SubscribeMessageWorker.java:74)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
```

Any help or insight is appreciated!

[image]

Comment: I didn't read your text thoroughly as it seems to contain a lot if irrelevant information (it not, I apologize) but what we're missing is your entity mapping. I assume that the elements in the list actually maintain the relation so just replacing the list won't help. I further assume you don't have any cascading or orphan removal so the replaced list won't get deleted (or inserts and deletes might be out of order). Why don't you try to update the existing list instead?

Comment: Another note: I'm no expert on blockchains but the use of "chain" indicates that the blocks themselves should have a relation to each other, right? So a block can only be part of a single block chain and can have only one parent or child. Why don't you model it that way, i.e. what is the `Blockchain` entity needed for?

Comment: @Thomas thanks for sharing. Yes it was orphan removal=true. When I added that bit, it started working. I would have tried updating the existing list but I didn't know how. I was just trying to find the first working way and now I can think of the optimal way. That said- usually the new chain will be an extended version of the former chain but sometimes it could have different earlier blocks (a forked chain) so it would make sense to remove those that no longer apply

Comment: @Thomas I don't know much about blockchain either actually. I'm learning as I go. Blocks do indeed have a direct (potential) relation to each other - or rather up to one other. block.last_hash = last_block.hash. It's like a backward facing linked list but only in data, not in actual memory reference. But I wanted blocks to be blind. I wanted the chain to be identified as such at a higher level of abstraction. I don't know if this is best but I wanted blocks to be islands.  A blockchain object has meta-data so the chain property of a blockchain is like the payload which is an ArrayList<Block>

Comment: @Thomas I just ended up doing it this way so I could add methods to blockchain like replaceChain() . Technically blocks can exist that are claimed by multiple chains. I don't know what I don't know so I just wanted flexibility. Something to claim a given set of blocks in an order and to provide other methods. It's part of a tutorial and also part of a reviewed case study for a professional paid training so I have evaluation rubrics to consider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. It seems to work with one extra annotation property `orphanRemoval=true` as below

```java
    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Block.class, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, orphanRemoval=true)
    @JoinTable(name = "BlocksByChain")
    List<Block> chain; // The chain itself
```

I knew it had to be simple and some feature that already existed. It was just not the framework default

EDIT: Not quite. Not perfectly. I still have to have code that flushes it out inside the DAO, and that is clunky and not optimal. Also I get a console output about a deadlock or something. I didn't notice that before as my application works as expected, but I know there has to be a better way.

This code also has to exist for it to work:

```java
    @Override
    public boolean replaceChain(String name, ArrayList<Block> new_chain) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException,
            ChainTooShortException, GenesisBlockInvalidException, BlocksInChainInvalidException {
        this.connect();
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        Query query = em.createQuery("select b from Blockchain b where b.instance_name = :name");
        query.setParameter("name", name);
        Blockchain blockchain = (Blockchain) query.getSingleResult();
//      blockchain.replace_chain(new_chain);
//      em.merge(blockchain);
        System.out.println("GOING TO REPLACE CHAIN AS SERVICE");

        // THIS LONG BLOCK IS BECAUSE I COULDN'T FIND A MORE NATURAL WAY. I KEEP GETTING
        // ERRORS.
        // I JUST WANT TO OVERWRITE THE CHAIN OR DO A SMART MERGE
        // INSTEAD IT TRIES TO APPEND. I HAVE TO WRITE AN EMPTY SET TO DB AND COMMIT IT
        // AND THEN REPOPULATE IT. ALTERNATELY I COULD MAYBE DO A NATIVE QUERY AND
        // TRUNCATE
        // REGARDLESS IT DOESN'T SEEM TO SMARTLY MERGE THE TWO CHAINS
        // -- IT SHOULD BE EASY WHEN THE NEW CHAIN IS AN EXTENSION, VS A FORK
        // -- HANDLING THE "FORK" POTENTIAL OF BLOCKCHAIN ADDS TO THE COMPLEXITY IN
        // WHICH CASE EASIEST TO TRUNCATE AND START FRESH
        
        
        
        // Try Flush
        if (blockchain.willReplace(new_chain)) {
            blockchain.setChain(null);
            em.getTransaction().commit();
            em.getTransaction().begin();
//          em.flush();
            Query query2 = em.createQuery("select b from Blockchain b where b.instance_name = :name");
            query.setParameter("name", name);
            Blockchain blockchain2 = (Blockchain) query.getSingleResult();
            blockchain2.setChain(new_chain);
            em.getTransaction().commit();
            this.disconnect();
            return true;
        }
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        this.disconnect();
        return true;
    }
```